# Poisson Probability (Shopkeeper Sales)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

[image]

SOLUTIONS:

- (A) 0.1804
- (B) 0.0166
- (C) 0.3233

Mean = 2/7*5

- (a) x = 3
- (b) x > 5

I'm still unsure how to approach each question, because I still get the wrong answers.

Comment: The mean per week is $2$ not  $3/7*5$.  Question (c) may be  $P(X \ge 3)$

Comment: sorry i meant to say 2*5/7

Isnt it 2 per week (7 days) but it is now 5 days so (5/7)*2 ??

Comment: All the questions are about a week.  You could say the mean is $2/5$ per trading day, but it would not help you answer the questions. Just use a mean of $2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have got the first two right. The last one is just the probability that he gets 3 or more orders, so you need 
$$
1-e^{-\lambda} - e^{-\lambda} \lambda -\frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^2}{2!}
$$
and you know $\lambda$.